# How can I get rid of the namespace prefix from MOXy json output?

Tags: json, jersey, moxy

Java 7, Jersey 2.17 + Jersey-media-moxy 2.17

All JAXB classes have the same namespace.
The FindResponse and ApipeApipe classes are in different package, the package-info class for both packages has the same annotation:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "xmlapi_1.0", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

The FindResponse class has the @XmlElementRoot,

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "findResponse")
public class FindResponse {
```

while the ApipeApipe class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "apipe.Apipe")
public class ApipeApipe extends VllVll {
```

The ObjectFactory for FindResponse:

```
public FindResponse createFindResponse() {
    return new FindResponse();
}
```

The ObjectFactory for ApipeApipe:

```
@XmlElementDecl(namespace = "xmlapi_1.0", name = "apipe.Apipe")
public JAXBElement<ApipeApipe> createApipeApipe(ApipeApipe value) {
    return new JAXBElement<ApipeApipe>(new QName("xmlapi_1.0", "apipe.Apipe"), ApipeApipe.class, null, value);
}
```

The custom MoxyJsonConfigResolver:

```
@Provider
public class MdmMoxyJsonConfigResolver implements ContextResolver<MoxyJsonConfig> {

    private final MoxyJsonConfig config;

    public MdmMoxyJsonConfigResolver() {
        final Map<String, String> namespacePrefixMapper = new HashMap<String, String>();
        namespacePrefixMapper.put(javax.xml.XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI, "xsi");
        namespacePrefixMapper.put("xmlapi_1.0", "");

        config = new MoxyJsonConfig()
                .setNamespacePrefixMapper(namespacePrefixMapper)
                .setNamespaceSeparator(':')
                .setAttributePrefix("@")
                .setValueWrapper("value")
                .property(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_WRAPPER_AS_ARRAY_NAME, true)
                .setFormattedOutput(true)
                .setIncludeRoot(true)
                .setMarshalEmptyCollections(true);      
    }

    @Override
    public MoxyJsonConfig getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return config;
    }
}
```

Json output:

```
{
   "findResponse" : {
      "result" : {
         "ns0:lag.Interface" : [ {
            "ns0:objectFullName" : "network:35.121.34.101:lag:interface-31",
            "ns0:selfAlarmed" : true,
            "ns0:name" : "interface-31",
            "ns0:administrativeState" : "portInService",
            "ns0:baseMacAddress" : "00-00-00-00-00-00",
            "ns0:cleiCode" : "N/A",
            "ns0:displayedName" : "Lag 31",
            "ns0:equipmentCategory" : "port",
            "ns0:equipmentState" : "equipmentOperationallyDown",
            "ns0:hardwareFailureReason" : "N/A"}]
}}}
```

I've set the namespace prefix to blank in the MoxyJsonConfig, it does not seem to work. How can I get rid of the namespace prefix, especially the one prepended to the attributes?

I've added a test to check the output in XML format:

The code:

```
    @Test
    public void testMoxyJaxb() throws Exception {

        ApipeApipe apipe = findService.findByOfn(ApipeApipe.class, "svc-mgr:service-96849");
        FindResponse findResponse = getFindResponse(Arrays.asList(apipe));

        {
            javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(getClassesToBeBound());
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            System.out.println("javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext output: ");
            marshaller.marshal(findResponse, System.out);
            System.out.println("");
        }

        {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.DEFAULT_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "xmlapi_1.0");
            javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbContext = org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(getClassesToBeBound(), properties);
            org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller marshaller = (org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller)jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            Map<String, Object> nsPrefix = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//          nsPrefix.put(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI, "xsi");
            nsPrefix.put("xmlapi_1.0", "");
            marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, nsPrefix);

            System.out.println("org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory output: ");
            marshaller.marshal(findResponse, System.out);
            System.out.println("");
        }

        {
            System.out.println("org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller output: ");
            Result result = new StringResult();
            jaxb.marshal(findResponse, result);
            System.out.println(result.toString());
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

The output:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext output: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"><result><apipe.Apipe><objectFullName>svc-mgr:service-96849</objectFullName><selfAlarmed>false</selfAlarmed><name>service-96849</name><groupPointer></groupPointer><id>96849</id><serviceId>500</serviceId><subscriberPointer>subscriber:1</subscriberPointer><administrativeState>down</administrativeState><description>N/A</description><displayedName>APIPE 500</displayedName><aggrOperationalState>down</aggrOperationalState><compositeSvcId>0</compositeSvcId><compositeSvcPointer></compositeSvcPointer><configuredNumberOfSites>0</configuredNumberOfSites><customerName>Default customer</customerName><mtuInconsistent>false</mtuInconsistent><numberOfCircuitsInconsistent>false</numberOfCircuitsInconsistent><numberOfConnector>0</numberOfConnector><numberOfInterfacesInconsistent>false</numberOfInterfacesInconsistent><numberOfSites>0</numberOfSites><numberOfSitesInconsistent>false</numberOfSitesInconsistent><olcState>maintenance</olcState><operationalFlags/><sasEntityName>A-pipe Service #500</sasEntityName><subscriberId>1</subscriberId><vcType>atmvcc</vcType></apipe.Apipe></result></findResponse>
org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory output: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><result><apipe.Apipe xmlns:ns0="xmlapi_1.0"><objectFullName>svc-mgr:service-96849</objectFullName><selfAlarmed>false</selfAlarmed><name>service-96849</name><groupPointer></groupPointer><id>96849</id><serviceId>500</serviceId><subscriberPointer>subscriber:1</subscriberPointer><administrativeState>down</administrativeState><description>N/A</description><displayedName>APIPE 500</displayedName><aggrOperationalState>down</aggrOperationalState><compositeSvcId>0</compositeSvcId><compositeSvcPointer></compositeSvcPointer><configuredNumberOfSites>0</configuredNumberOfSites><customerName>Default customer</customerName><mtuInconsistent>false</mtuInconsistent><numberOfCircuitsInconsistent>false</numberOfCircuitsInconsistent><numberOfConnector>0</numberOfConnector><numberOfInterfacesInconsistent>false</numberOfInterfacesInconsistent><numberOfSites>0</numberOfSites><numberOfSitesInconsistent>false</numberOfSitesInconsistent><olcState>maintenance</olcState><operationalFlags/><sasEntityName>A-pipe Service #500</sasEntityName><subscriberId>1</subscriberId><vcType>atmvcc</vcType></apipe.Apipe></result></findResponse>
org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller output: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><findResponse xmlns="xmlapi_1.0"><result><apipe.Apipe><objectFullName>svc-mgr:service-96849</objectFullName><selfAlarmed>false</selfAlarmed><name>service-96849</name><groupPointer></groupPointer><id>96849</id><serviceId>500</serviceId><subscriberPointer>subscriber:1</subscriberPointer><administrativeState>down</administrativeState><description>N/A</description><displayedName>APIPE 500</displayedName><aggrOperationalState>down</aggrOperationalState><compositeSvcId>0</compositeSvcId><compositeSvcPointer></compositeSvcPointer><configuredNumberOfSites>0</configuredNumberOfSites><customerName>Default customer</customerName><mtuInconsistent>false</mtuInconsistent><numberOfCircuitsInconsistent>false</numberOfCircuitsInconsistent><numberOfConnector>0</numberOfConnector><numberOfInterfacesInconsistent>false</numberOfInterfacesInconsistent><numberOfSites>0</numberOfSites><numberOfSitesInconsistent>false</numberOfSitesInconsistent><olcState>maintenance</olcState><operationalFlags/><sasEntityName>A-pipe Service #500</sasEntityName><subscriberId>1</subscriberId><vcType>atmvcc</vcType></apipe.Apipe></result></findResponse>
```

There's an additional namespace attribute on  tag of the org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller output. It's not there in the other two marshaller's output. Is this the reason the namespace prefix is prepended to the attribute name of the JSON output?